# Solarized in NeoVim on iTerm 1 and 2 has incorrect background for dark theme

Tags: vim, iterm2, neovim

I'm trying to use the Solarized theme for vim in NeoVim. However, despite setting the `background` to "dark" and confirming it's set to dark, the solarized background color is a very light grey, almost white color.  Setting `background=light` only adjusts the color of text.

I'm using iTerm2 (but had this issue with iTerm 1 and thought switching might fix). And I'm using the solarized dark theme in the iTerm2 profile.  I also have the CSApprox plugin installed.  I've confirmed both `&t_Co=256` and `term=xterm-256colors`.  I've noticed background colors being slightly off for other themes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this one myself.  After verifying this wasn't an issue by using vim instead of NeoVim, the problem was I was not using [NeoVim TrueColor support.](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/2198)

Enabling this using the environment variable `NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1`. Adding

```
export NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
```

to my `.bash_profile` fixed the issue. All schemes now look as advertised.